# Grad level books for survivability analysis applied to manufacturing

Tags: r, references, reliability, engineering-statistics

I am looking for a grad level book on survivability analysis applied to manufacturing such as assembly lines. Preferably in R. I am familiar with measure theory, probability theory and R.

Comment: Could you clarify "reliability analysis"? - at least one meaning of that term is synonymous with "survival analysis", i.e. the analysis of (possibly censored) time-to-event data. Reliability engineering on the other hand employs a much broader variety of statistical methods.

Comment: It's "survival analysis" (in Medical Statistics, & often enough in general statistical usage) or "reliability analysis" (in Engineering Statistics).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another nice resource (but no R) is provided by:

O'Connor, P.D.T. & Kleyner, A. (2012). Practical Reliability Engineering. Wiley

[http://www.amazon.com/Practical-Reliability-Engineering-Patrick-OConnor/dp/047097981X](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/047097981X)

It has a more in-situ treatment, which I believe is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 3):

The following used to be standard texts for engineering statistics, & have been through many editions:

- Box Hunter & Hunter, *Statistics for Experimenters*
- Montgomery, *Design & Analysis of Experiments*
- Montgomery, *Statistical Process Control*

Both the Montgomery books also had copious supplemental material online. (I just looked & it still exists; I also happened on the [*R Companion to Design and Analysis of Experiments*](http://www.aliquote.org/articles/tech/dae/).

You might also want an general introductory book on Statistics

Comment: Go for Box, Hunter & Hunter, the Montgomery Design book have errors (the other Montgomery book I do not know)

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen: Could you elaborate on the errors?

Comment: :I do not have that Montgomery book with me now (and what I have seen was a spanish translation), but my impression was that the book was old-fashioned, and conceptually weaker than BHH. The error was in the interpretation of an ANOVA table, where the wrong sumsquare was used for error in the F test.